# Why isn't my designer property serialized in the ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, editor, controls, datasource

In an attempt to create a custom data source that is supposed to be used in ASP.NET, I've created a custom data source class, a custom editor and a custom serializable class.

What I fail to understand is why it doesn't work... even though I probably have more attributes than required (I've been browsing and trying things for hours), from what I understand the `PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)` should have done the trick... Also, it seems to me like my code is similar to [Why can't I declare sub-elements (properties) of a UserControl in a WebForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743680/why-cant-i-declare-sub-elements-properties-of-a-usercontrol-in-a-webform) .

The code works as follows:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class MyDataSource : DataSourceControl
{
    // [much more irrelevant code...]

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [MergableProperty(false)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(Editors.ResultRequestEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public ResultRequest Request { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[PersistChildren(true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[ParseChildren(true)]    
public class ResultRequest
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public Type ColumnType { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public object[] ResultTypeParameters { get; set; }
}
```

The custom editor seems to work: after using it, the properties in VS are updated correctly.

However, after updating something the information is not persisted in the ASPX file:

```
<cc1:MyDataSource ID="SearchDataSource1" runat="server" ProviderID="MyProvider1" />
```

What I expected was some serialization within the data source, e.g.:

```
<cc1:MyDataSource ID="SearchDataSource1" runat="server" ProviderID="MyProvider1">
    <Request>
        // blah
    </Request>
</cc1:MyDataSource>
```

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried without some attributes, for example the TypeConverters?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Basicly your are saying: I have three classes, and they don't work. What are your trying to do? What is your obeserved behavior and your expected behavior? You expect some serialization in the datasource? Serialization in a class? Normally serialization occurs inside a text or binary file. So my next question would: What file?

Comment: Well basically I'm trying to make a custom editor for the `ResultRequest` class. The data source itself works, I just can't get it to be configured from the ASPX instead of the code behind. The TypeConverters are there because default serialization (to your ASPX XML) doesn't work - f.ex. while I know how to serialize the `object[]`, the designer doesn't, so I intended to tell him how that's done. That's also what the editor is for. Yes, I tried adding and removing attributes for hours in an attempt to understand how it works (conclusion: it doesn't work and I don't understand it).

Comment: @SimonMourier so to answer your question, yes I did try, but I cannot see how that could possibly work (after all, the designed doesn't know how to serialize the `ResultRequest` data back and forth to the ASPX file); from what I understand I need a `TypeConverter` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my sample it's less complex so it would be easier to understand:

First parent control (in your case this would be DataSource):

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TabContainer runat=server></{0}:TabContainer>")]
[ParseChildren(ChildrenAsProperties = false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class TabContainer : Panel, INamingContainer
{

    #region private properties

    List<TabItem> tabs = new List<TabItem>();

    #endregion

    [Bindable(true)]
    public event EventHandler TabClick;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public List<TabItem> Tabs
    {
        get { return this.tabs; }
    }
}
```

Take notice I have set ChildrenAsProperties to false. And here is child definition, TabItem:

```
public class TabItem : Panel, IPostBackEventHandler
{


    String clientClick = String.Empty;

    public event EventHandler Click;


    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Text"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = "";
            }
            return (string)ViewState["Text"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside designer I can declare TabContainer like this:

```
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"
        </cc1:TabContainer>
```

And finally add child controls that preserve state:

```
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"
            OnTabClick="TabContainer_TabClick">
            <Tabs>
                <cc1:TabItem ID="Tab1" Text="Hello" runat="server" />
                <cc1:TabItem ID="Tab2" Text="World" runat="server" />
            </Tabs>
        </cc1:TabContainer>
```

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not really a solution: the issue is partly that the `object[]` and `Type` needs to be serialized. `IList<T>` with `T` a serialiable type is serializable and therefore works with `PersistenceMode`, whereas my example doesn't. I'm mostly having trouble combining all these attributes and understanding how to glue it all together... Perhaps if you made your example a bit more complex, it would be comparable?